# Shadowbox not working after ajax load data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, shadowbox

Shadowbox is unable to work after ajax load data.
I tried to put in Shadowbox.init() to ajax load function and also in the php page. Nothing works. Shadowbox is working fine before ajax loaded data.

```
    $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url: url1,
                data: {offset:offset},
                dataType: "html",
                timeout: 10000,
                success:function(data) {
                Shadowbox.init();
                    if(data == 0){
                            $("#nodeal").show();
                            $(".more_deals").hide();
                            $("#nomore").val(1);
                            $('#loadimage').hide();
                        }else {
                            Shadowbox.init();
                            $("#nodeal").hide();
                            $(".more_deals").hide();
                            $('.loadmoredeals').append(data); 
                            $('#loadimage').hide();
                        }
                },
                error:function(request, status, err) {
                    if(status == "timeout") {
                        gotoagain(offset);
                    }

                }
            });
```

PHP page for html Result: (firefox can work with this code , chrome and IE not working with this code)

```
$html = "<script src='/static/js/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js'></script>    
            <script>
                Shadowbox.init();
            </script>";
```

Does running shadowbox javascript caused the error? How do i make the shadowbox work?

Comment: What does your debugging console (for example firebug) say?

Comment: What errors appear in the error console of the browser?

Comment: No error in firefox. Working fine in firefox.

no error in chrome.. page just stop working. 

IE error - access denied

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Shadowbox.init({ skipSetup: true }); Shadowbox.setup();
```

instead of 
Shadowbox.init();

Answer (score 1):

Got it work already.

Solution From http://shadowbox.1309102.n2.nabble.com/Documents-loaded-through-ajax-shadowbox-not-working-td1309124.html

We can only call Shadowbox.init(); 1 time. Therefor error occurs when i called Shadowbox.init(); in ajax load.