# Wordpress Shadowbox not working with Infinite Scroll

Tags: wordpress, callback, infinite-scroll, shadowbox

i've been looking into this and cannot find the answer and would really appreciate any help.

i have the shadowbox plugin and the infinite scroll, but i can't for the life of me figure out the callback i need to put into the infinite scroll to keep loading the shadowbox once the 'archive' pages start loading.

right now i have:

Shadowbox.init(shadowbox_conf);

but it's not working.

please help,

thanks so much

Comment: found the answer, on the callback text-field you need to add: 

`Shadowbox.init({ skipSetup: true }); Shadowbox.setup();` 

thanks to this thread: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944397/shadowbox-not-working-after-ajax-load-data]